# How to pass a string to a selector in Objective C (inside a UITableView Cell)

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have implemented a UITableView and inside each cell I have two buttons. When one of them is pressed I need to pass a string taken from the cell in question to another method [ShowMeThePassedString]. For the sake of simplicity in the code below I am trying to retrieve a global variable.

This is my code, but I get the following error: “unrecognized selector sent to instance”. Any suggestion please? Thanks!

```
//in .h
- (NSString *) ShowMeThePassedString:(NSString*) TESTvalue;

//in .m
NSString *TEST_string = @"Hi there!";

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //…

     //Add a button
     button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]
     [button setTitle:@“Show me the string“ forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     button.frame = CGRectMake(260, cell.center.y - 15, 53, 30);
     [button addTarget:self action:@selector(ShowMeThePassedString:TEST_string:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [cell addSubview:button];
}

- (NSString *) ShowMeThePassedString:(NSString*) TESTvalue
{
    NSLog(@"TEST result %@", TESTvalue);
    return TESTvalue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change to this

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(ShowMeThePassedString:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


- (NSString *) ShowMeThePassedString:(id)sender
{    
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
    NSLog(@"TEST result %@", button.titleLabel);
    return button.titleLabel;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it would work for my purpose, which is accessing the string stored inside that particular cell (I should have not "simplified" the question using a global variable!

Comment: Ok hold on I'll fix in a different answer